# Strange behaviour of browser console and jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I hide `input["type"]` for styling "browse file" button.

```
<input type="file" id="photoUpload" multiple style="display: none"/>

<button class="addFile" id="fakePhotoUpload">&nbsp;</button>
```

I try trigger click on a hidden `input["type"]` via jQuery function

```
$('#fakePhotoUpload').click(function() {
    $('#photoUpload').click();
});
```

**This code performs and working like a charm.**

But, if I call it function

```
$('#photoUpload').click();
```

from browser **console** (Google Chrome) **nothing happens**.

Who can explain this behaviour of console?

Comment: Try with `$('#photoUpload')[0].click();`

Comment: In XHTML, attribute minimization is forbidden, and the multiple attribute must be defined as <input multiple="multiple" />.

Comment: looks fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dQvTQ/1/

Comment: make sure your code is in a dom ready handler/is running after the target element is added to the dom

Comment: That's for security purpose, you cannot open browser file dialog without any user interraction, here a click

Comment: @Satpal, it's not working also.

Comment: Look at this not working example: http://jsfiddle.net/dQvTQ/2/ . Please explain why if you know.

Comment: I think most of you misread the question which is how to open browser file dialog without clicking. And answer is you cannot (on modern browsers)

Comment: There's no way to do this? How depressing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> That's for security purpose, you cannot open browser file dialog
>   without any user interraction, In your example, a click made anywhere on the page.

If you could, then it should be fixed urgently!

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution but is very helpful:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#fakePhotoUpload').click(function () {
        $('#photoUpload').click();
    });
    $('#photoUpload').click(function(e){
        alert('hi');//make your own dialog box here. use UI dialog box.
    });
    $('#photoUpload').click();
})
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dQvTQ/3/)